# Proving that $\tan \theta=\cot(90^\circ-\theta)$ when $\theta>90^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

> I'm asked to prove $\tan \theta=\cot (90-\theta)$

[image]

So $\tan \theta =\frac{a}{b}=\cot(90^\circ-\theta)$

But what if $\theta>90?$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identities
$$
\sin(x-y)=\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y
$$
and 
$$
\cos(x-y)=\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y
$$
to deduce that
$$
\sin(90^{\circ}-\theta)=\cos\theta;\quad \cos(90^{\circ}-\theta)=\sin\theta.
$$
Hence
$$
\cot(90^{\circ}-\theta)
=\frac{\cos(90^{\circ}-\theta)}{\sin(90^{\circ}-\theta)}
=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
=\tan\theta.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $0^\circ<\alpha<90^\circ$.

**Second and third quadrants**:

If $\theta=180^\circ\pm\alpha$, then
$$\begin{align}
\text{RHS}&=\cot(90^\circ-\theta)\\
&=\cot(90^\circ-(180^\circ\pm\alpha))\\
&=\cot(-90^\circ\mp\alpha)\\
&=\cot(-(90^\circ\pm\alpha))\\
&=-\cot(90^\circ\pm\alpha)\\
&=\mp\tan\alpha\\
\text{LHS}&=\tan\theta\\
&=\tan(180^\circ\pm\alpha)\\
&=\mp\tan\alpha\\
&=\text{RHS}
\end{align}$$

**Fourth quadrant**:

If $\theta=-\alpha$, then
$$\begin{align}
\text{RHS}&=\cot(90^\circ-\theta)\\
&=\cot(90^\circ+\alpha)\\
&=\cot(180^\circ-(90^\circ -\alpha))\\
&=-\cot(90^\circ-\alpha))\\
&=-\tan\alpha\\
\text{LHS}&=\tan\theta\\
&=\tan(-\alpha)\\
&=-\tan\alpha\\
&=\text{RHS}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this using the fact $\sin(\theta) = \cos(90^\circ - \theta)$ for all $\theta \in \Bbb R$:

$$ \begin{align*}
\tan(90^\circ-  \theta) &= \frac{\sin(90^\circ - \theta)}{\cos(90^\circ -
 \theta)} \\
&= \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin( \theta)} \\
&= \cot(\theta)
\end{align*}. $$

Comment: There is a typographical error in $\tan(90^\circ - \theta)$.  Also, we want to prove $\cot(90^\circ - \theta) = \tan\theta$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The proof is the same. Just set $\varphi = 90^\circ - \theta$. Then you get $\tan(90^\circ - (90^\circ - \varphi)) = \cot(90^\circ - \varphi)$, so $\cot(90^\circ - \varphi) = \tan(\varphi)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be noted that the $\tan(\theta) = \frac{opp}{adj}$ and $\cot(\theta) = \frac{adj}{opp}$ are only defined for acute triangles. If $\theta>90$, then to extend the notion of trigonometric functions to obtuse angles, let $r$ be the distance $|OP|$ between the origin $O$ and $P$ is the point at $(x,y)$. Then, $\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x}$ and $\cot(\theta) = \frac{x}{y}$. This line of reasoning should be suggestive, since you are considering an angle larger than 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#/media/File:Circle-trig6.svg) from the Wikipedia article on [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions). Tangent is the directed length of the segment of the circle's tangent line (tangent at the correct angle) between the circle and the $x$-axis. Cotangent is the length of the segment of the tangent line that connects to the $y$-axis. The direction, and thus the sign, of each is defined such that it alternates as you go from quadrant to quadrant.

Answer (score -1):

At a point the angle of elevation of the top of a tower is such that its tangent is 5/12 . On walking 80m towards the tower, the cotangent of the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is 4/3. The height of the tower will be how much m?